# Link deactivating on Ajax load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having a problem with my AJAX function.

I'am generating my articles dynamically with object oriented PHP, and if the SESSION = admin you can modify that article.

My php code works correctly without it but every time I put AJAX on, the modification link works before the event load and then dies.

I know that AJAX don't reload the DOM so I figured that might be the issue here.
Since I am quite a new to AJAX I haven't been able to make it work yet.

PHP Code:

```
<div id="articles">

<?php

$article = new Article('','','','','');

//  Liste des produits
$articles  = Article::listeArticle(); //Apel de la fonction qui liste les marques dans un select
$compteur=0;


// Generation des articles

foreach ($articles as $article)
{
    $compteur++;

    echo "<div class='accordion'>";
        echo "<div class='accordion-section'>";
            echo '<a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-'.$compteur.'">';
                $article->getTitre();
                echo " ";
                $article->getDate();
            echo "</a>";
            echo '<div class="accordion-section-content" id="accordion-'.$compteur.'">';
                echo "<p>";
                    $article->getContenu();
                echo "</p>";
                echo "<h3>Auteur : ";
                $article->getIdAuteur();
                echo "</h3>";
                // On verifie si l'utilisateur est authentifié si c'est le cas on donne la possibilité de modifier un article
                if((isset($_SESSION["authentifie"]))&& $roleUtilisateurEncours == 1 )
                      {
                        echo '<a href="gestionArticle.php?action=modifier&idArticle=' .$article->getIdArticle().'"/>'. 'Modifier article</a>';
                      }
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}

?>
</div>
```

My AJAX function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    $("#articles").load('index.php #articles')
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is not working? Which elements, what happens/should happen etc?

Comment: When i first load the page all links are working perfectly, but after the AJAX load (every 5 secs) the links dies.  `echo '<a href="gestionArticle.php?action=modifier&idArticle=' .$article->getIdArticle().'"/>'. 'Modifier article</a>';` This link is not a link after the Ajax load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery Manual: http://api.jquery.com/load/

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.
>
> `$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );`
>
> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.

In your jQuery example, you specified and id with (#articles) which is not found in the remote document (index.php).

You need to justify this part to match with the ids in the remote document, or just load all content.

Comment: Hi Akam, and thx for the answer but the id articles is the id of my first div ^^ I should have explain it better but my english is not that great : The link `a href` after the load (ajax) execution is dead and become non clickable